# htaccess redirect with text on URL

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

I tried to redirect a mobile site if not contain a text on the url but I receive error.
Can somebody help me please?
I have this code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} iphone|ipad|android|blackberry|ipod [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !"?id\=m" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/blog\.misite\.com\/\?id\=m$1" [R=301,L]
```

The idea is if are mobile, redirect to blog.misite.com/?id\=m and the rest of URL
but if now contains ?id\=m doesnt redirect.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This *probably* is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} iphone|ipad|android|blackberry|ipod [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^(?:[^&]*&)*id=m [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://blog.example.com/?id=m$1 [R=301]
```

Take care however that you do not implement an endless rewriting rule.